# Prevent page to rebuild in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, state, builder, rebuild

I am using widget `Image` in flutter and it contains ternary or conditional statement.. here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build widget");
    return Image(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      image: AssetImage('flutter.png'),
      frameBuilder: (context, child, frame, wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
        if (wasSynchronouslyLoaded)
          return child;
        else {
          return AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: frame != null ? child : widget.placeholder,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

So, it depends on `frame` value, when the value changes.. the widget will be rebuilt from the start. In my case,  `print("build widget");` will be printed 2 times. Actually I am wrapping my widget with `ValueListenableBuilder`, so that it will be built only for widget that changes, it seems that I can not wrap the code abode using `ValueListenableBuilder`. So, is there a way to prevent the code above to build 2 times ?